# Raspberry Pi 5 bad video signal after power cycling monitor

Tags: pi-5

I just setup my new Raspberry Pi 5 8GB with a small LG TV as the monitor. Native screen resolution is 1360x768, which works fine. At night I power off the monitor but leave the RP5 running. When I power on the TV the next morning, the display only shows a grey background and the mouse is inverted, as if the screen resolution was "rotated" for a sideways display. Though the mouse moves (sideways), I cannot open any menus or access any settings or terminal window so the only recourse seems to be to hard reboot the Pi. I have no idea where to even begin troubleshooting this, anyone have an idea? Thanks!

Comment: what model is the LG?

Comment: LH4830  https://www.lg.com/us/tvs/lg-24LH4830-PU-led-tv